# Parameter estimation of a Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, estimation-theory

Let $a,b$ two real numbers, $\theta$ a real parameter and suppose that you have an analytic function of the form:
$$
f_\theta(x)\triangleq \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k(\theta)x^k \quad\forall x\in[a,b],
$$
where $a_k$ are known functions of $\theta$. Moreover assume that you have $n\in\mathbb{N}$ *observations of $f_\theta$*, i.e., you know $n$ tuples $(x_i,f_\theta(x_i))$.

Let's consider the problem of estimating $\theta$ from the observations at hand. One natural way is to define for $N\in\mathbb{N}$ the truncated function
$$
\tilde{f}_\theta^N(x)\triangleq \sum_{k=0}^Na_k(\theta)x^k\quad \forall x\in[a,b],
$$
and $\hat{\theta}^N$ as:
$$
\hat{\theta}^N = \text{argmin}_s\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\tilde{f}_s^N(x_i)-f_\theta(x_i)\right)^2.$$

### Problem

If we assume that the function
$$
\phi : \theta\mapsto f_\theta
$$
is injective, can we find an integer $m$ such that
$$
\|\hat{\theta}^N-\theta\| = o(N^{-m})\;?
$$
Thank you very much for the help!